# AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'chat'

Tags: py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

**I want to create a variable,
message.chat.id outside of function
for example like this**

```
bot = telebot.teleBot("token")
global message
message = bot.message.chat.id

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def welcome():
    bot.send_message(message,"Welcome on here, pls describe yourself")
```

but the telebot attributes error
does the message argument always have to be inside the function, it can't be outside the function to become a variable?

Answer (score 0):

### I think this would be more appropriate code

```
bot = telebot.teleBot("token")
global message
message = message.chat.id

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def welcome(message):
    global message
    bot.send_message(message,"Welcome on here, pls describe yourself")
```

**alternatively just use bot.reply_to(message,"Hello Bros")
you can find the full docs** [here](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html?highlight=bot.reply_to#telebot.TeleBot.reply_to)